# Android - Object to hold 4 items

Tags: java, android, string, object

I am using Android 2.1

I need to know how to mash 4 items (String, String, String, String) into a single item
that i could enter into an array (to display on a listview).

Comment: Learn how to write custom classes.

Comment: @Pisti You don't get to dictate who writes what--it's the exact same comment as the answers which are getting voted up, and the most concise way of explaining what you need to do. It's also about as basic Java as you can get, and if it hadn't crossed your mind already, it might be a good time to take a step back and focus on some basics before going much further--it will only help you in the long run.

Comment: @Pisti writing a custom class would be very useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom class with a method that has four parameters. Now you can use this class anywhere you want. Please study following example.

```
public class myObjectClass
{
      String str1,str2,str3,str4;

      // Setting the values 
      public void setString1 ( String str1 )
      {
            this.str1 = str1;
      }
      public void setString2 ( String str2 )
      {
            this.str2 = str2;
      }
      public void setString3 ( String str3 )
      {
            this.str3 = str3;
      }
      public void setString4 ( String str4 )
      {
            this.str4 = str4;
      }

      // Gettng the values
      public String getString1 ()
      {
            return str1;
      }
      public String getString2 ()
      {
            return str2;
      }
      public String getString3 ()
      {
            return str3;
      }
      public String getString4 ()
      {
            return str4;
      }

      public void myObjects ( String str1, String str2, String str3,String str4 )
      {
             // Your Operation Code
      }
}
```

Comment: getters shouldn't have arguments. I've submitted an edit for that.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, yes I agree, i just write code so fast, that i forgot it. thanks for remining my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You could just define a class for that object which has a field for each string. Depending on what you would like to be displayed in the list view you should override the toString() method of this class too.

Answer (score 2):

Write a class ala

```
public class MyClass {
     private String field1;
     private String field2;
     private String field3;
     private String field4;

     public MyClass(String field1, String field2, String field3, String field4) {
         this.field1 = field1;
         //... etc etc
     }

     public String getField1() { return field1;}
     public void setField1(String field1) {this.field1 = field1;}

     //etc etc
}
```